# Get risk predictions in WEKA using own Java code

Tags: java, machine-learning, weka, probability, prediction

I already checked the ["*Making predictions*"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions) documentation of WEKA and it contains explicit instructions for command line and GUI predictions.

I want to know how to get a prediction value like the one below I got from the GUI using the `Agrawal` dataset (`weka.datagenerators.classifiers.classification.Agrawal`) in my own Java code:

```
inst#,  actual,     predicted,  error,  prediction
1,      1:0,        2:1,        +,      0.941
2,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
3,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
4,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
5,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
6,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
7,      1:0,        2:1,        +,      0.941
8,      2:1,        2:1,        ,       0.941
9,      2:1,        2:1,        ,       0.941
10,     2:1,        2:1,        ,       0.941
1,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
2,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
3,      1:0,        1:0,        ,       1
```

---

I can't replicate this result even though [it](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions#Java) said that:

> ### Java
>
> If you want to perform the classification within your own code, see the [classifying instances](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Classifying-instances) section of [this article](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code), explaining the Weka API in general.

I went to the [link](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Classifying-instances) and it said:

> ### Classifying instances
>
> In case you have an unlabeled dataset that you want to classify with your newly trained classifier, you can use the following code snippet. It loads the file `/some/where/unlabeled.arff`, uses the previously built classifier tree to label the instances, and saves the labeled data as `/some/where/labeled.arff`.

This is not the case I want because I just want the *k*-fold cross validation predictions on my current dataset modeled.

---

#### Update

> **`predictions`**
>
> `public FastVector predictions()`
>
> Returns the predictions that have been collected.
>
> Returns:
>
> > a reference to the `FastVector` containing the predictions that have been collected. This should be null if no predictions have been collected.

I found the [`predictions()`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) method for objects of type [`Evaluation`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) and by using the code:

```
Object[] preds = evaluation.predictions().toArray();
for(Object pred : preds) {
    System.out.println(pred);
}
```

It resulted to:

```
...
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.9466666666666667 0.05333333333333334
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.8947368421052632 0.10526315789473684
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.9934883720930232 0.0065116279069767444
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.9466666666666667 0.05333333333333334
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.9912575655682583 0.008742434431741762
NOM: 0.0 0.0 1.0 0.9934883720930232 0.0065116279069767444
...
```

Is this the same thing as the one above?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

After deep Google searches (and because the [documentation provides minimal help](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code#Classification-Classifying-instances)) I finally found the answer.

I hope this explicit answer helps others in the future.

- For a sample code I saw the question ["*How to print out the predicted class after cross-validation in WEKA*"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7314684/1685185) and I'm glad I was able to decode the incomplete answer wherein some of it is hard to understand.

  Here is my code that worked similar to the GUI's output

  ```
  StringBuffer predictionSB = new StringBuffer();
  Range attributesToShow = null;
  Boolean outputDistributions = new Boolean(true);

  PlainText predictionOutput = new PlainText();
  predictionOutput.setBuffer(predictionSB);
  predictionOutput.setOutputDistribution(true);

  Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(data);
  evaluation.crossValidateModel(j48Model, data, numberOfFolds,
          randomNumber, predictionOutput, attributesToShow,
          outputDistributions);
  ```

  To help you understand, we need to implement the `StringBuffer` to be casted in an [`AbstractOutput`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/output/prediction/AbstractOutput.html) object so that the function `crossValidateModel` can recognize it.

  Using `StringBuffer` only will cause a `java.lang.ClassCastException` similar the one in the question while using a `PlainText` without a `StringBuffer` will show a `java.lang.IllegalStateException`.

  I would like to thank [ManChon U (Kevin)](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/template/NamlServlet.jtp?macro=user_nodes&user=713) and their question ["*How to identify the cross-evaluation result to its corresponding instance in the input data set?*"](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/How-to-identify-the-cross-evaluation-result-to-its-corresponding-instance-in-the-input-data-set-tp22504.html) for giving me a clue on what this meant:

  > ... you just need a single addition argument that is a concrete subclass of  `weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.AbstractOutput`. `weka.classifiers.evaluation.output.prediction.PlainText` is probably the 
  >   one you want to use. [Source](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Print-out-the-predict-class-after-cross-validation-tp15066p15070.html)

  and

  > ... Try creating a `PlainText` object, which extends `AbstractOutput` (called output for example) instance and calling `output.setBuffer(forPredictionsPrinting)` and passing that in instead of the buffer. [Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314684/how-to-print-out-the-predicted-class-after-cross-validation-in-weka#comment8913986_7317395)

  These just actually meant to create a `PlainText` object, put a `StringBuffer` in it and use it to tweak the output with methods `setOutput(boolean)` and others.

  Finally, to get our desired predictions, just use:

  ```
  System.out.println(predictionOutput.getBuffer());
  ```

  Wherein `predictionOutput` is an object from the [`AbstractOutput`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/evaluation/output/prediction/AbstractOutput.html) family (`PlainText`, `CSV`, `XML`, etc).
- Additionally, the results of `evaluation.predictions()` is different from the one provided in the WEKA GUI.  Fortunately Mark Hall explained this in the question ["*Print out the predict class after cross-validation*"](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Print-out-the-predict-class-after-cross-validation-tp15066p15070.html)

  > `Evaluation.predictions()` returns a `FastVector` containing either `NominalPrediction` or `NumericPrediction` objects from the `weka.classifiers.evaluation` package. Calling 
  >   `Evaluation.crossValidateModel()` with the additional `AbstractOutput` object results in the evaluation object printing the  prediction/distribution information from `Nominal`/`NumericPrediction` objects to the `StringBuffer` in the format that you see in the Explorer or from the command line.

References:

- ["*Print out the predict class after cross-validation*"](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/Print-out-the-predict-class-after-cross-validation-td15066.html)
- ["*How to identify the cross-evaluation result to its corresponding instance in the input data set?*"](http://weka.8497.n7.nabble.com/How-to-identify-the-cross-evaluation-result-to-its-corresponding-instance-in-the-input-data-set-td22504.html)
- ["*How to print out the predicted class after cross-validation in WEKA*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7314684/how-to-print-out-the-predicted-class-after-cross-validation-in-weka)