# Get prediction percentage in WEKA using own Java code and a model

Tags: java, machine-learning, classification, weka, prediction

### Overview

I know that one can get the percentages of each prediction in a trained WEKA model through the GUI and command line options as conveniently explained and demonstrated in the documentation article ["*Making predictions*"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions).

[image: WHAT I WANT WITH MY WEKA OOOHH *LADY GAGA PIANO*]

#### Predictions

I know that there are three ways documented to get these predictions:

1. [command line](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions#Command%20line)
2. [GUI](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Making+predictions#GUI)
3. Java code/using the WEKA API, which I was able to do in the answer to ["*Get risk predictions in WEKA using own Java code*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21424248/get-risk-predictions-in-weka-using-own-java-code)
4. this fourth one requires a generated WEKA `.MODEL` file

I have a trained `.MODEL` file and now **I want to classify new instances using this together with the prediction percentages** similar to the one below (an output of the GUI's Explorer, in `CSV` format):

```
inst#,actual,predicted,error,distribution,
1,1:0,2:1,+,0.399409,*0.7811
2,1:0,2:1,+,0.3932409,*0.8191
3,1:0,2:1,+,0.399409,*0.600591
4,1:0,2:1,+,0.139409,*0.64
5,1:0,2:1,+,0.399409,*0.600593
6,1:0,2:1,+,0.3993209,*0.600594
7,1:0,2:1,+,0.500129,*0.600594
8,1:0,2:1,+,0.399409,*0.90011
9,1:0,2:1,+,0.211409,*0.60182
10,1:0,2:1,+,0.21909,*0.11101
```

The `predicted` column is what I want to get from a `.MODEL` file.

---

### What I know

Based from my experience with the WEKA API approach, one can get these predictions using the following code (the `PlainText` inserted into an `Evaluation` object) BUT I do not want to do *k*-fold cross-validation that is provided by the `Evaluation` object.

```
StringBuffer predictionSB = new StringBuffer();
Range attributesToShow = null;
Boolean outputDistributions = new Boolean(true);

PlainText predictionOutput = new PlainText();
predictionOutput.setBuffer(predictionSB);
predictionOutput.setOutputDistribution(true);

Evaluation evaluation = new Evaluation(data);
evaluation.crossValidateModel(j48Model, data, numberOfFolds,
        randomNumber, predictionOutput, attributesToShow,
        outputDistributions);

System.out.println(predictionOutput.getBuffer());
```

#### From the WEKA documentation

Note that a `.MODEL` file classifies data from an `.ARFF` or related input is discussed in ["Use Weka in your Java code"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Use+Weka+in+your+Java+code) and ["*Serialization*"](http://weka.wikispaces.com/Serialization) a.k.a. "*How to use a `.MODEL` file in your own Java code to classify new instances*" (why the vague title smfh).

#### Using own Java code to classify

Loading a `.MODEL` file is through "Deserialization" and the following is for versions > 3.5.5:

```
// deserialize model
Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read("/some/where/j48.model");
```

An `Instance` object is the data and it is fed to the `classifyInstance`. An output is provided here (depending on the data type of the outcome attribute):

```
// classify an Instance object (testData)
cls.classifyInstance(testData.instance(0));
```

The question ["*How to reuse saved classifier created from explorer(in weka) in eclipse java*"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017957/how-to-reuse-saved-classifier-created-from-explorerin-weka-in-eclipse-java) has a great answer too!

### Javadocs

I have already checked the Javadocs for [`Classifier`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Classifier.html) (the trained model) and [`Evaluation`](http://weka.sourceforge.net/doc.dev/weka/classifiers/Evaluation.html) (just in case) but none directly and explicitly addresses this issue.

The only thing closest to what I want is the `classifyInstances` method of the `Classifier`:

> Classifies the given test instance. The instance has to belong to a dataset when it's being classified. Note that a classifier MUST implement either this or distributionForInstance().

---

How can I simultaneously use a WEKA `.MODEL` file to classify and get predictions of a new instance using my own Java code (aka using the WEKA API)?

[image: WHAT I WANT WITH MY WEKA OOOHH *LADY GAGA PIANO*]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This answer simply updates my answer from [How to reuse saved classifier created from explorer(in weka) in eclipse java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20017957/how-to-reuse-saved-classifier-created-from-explorerin-weka-in-eclipse-java/20019031#20019031).

I will show how to obtain the predicted instance value and the prediction percentage (or distribution).  The example model is a J48 decision tree created and saved in the Weka Explorer.  It was built from the nominal weather data provided with Weka.  It is called "tree.model".

```
import weka.classifiers.Classifier;
import weka.core.Instances;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String rootPath="/some/where/"; 
        Instances originalTrain= //instances here

        //load model
        Classifier cls = (Classifier) weka.core.SerializationHelper.read(rootPath+"tree.model");

        //predict instance class values
        Instances originalTrain= //load or create Instances to predict

        //which instance to predict class value
        int s1=0;

        //perform your prediction
        double value=cls.classifyInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1));

        //get the prediction percentage or distribution
        double[] percentage=cls.distributionForInstance(originalTrain.instance(s1));

        //get the name of the class value
        String prediction=originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int)value); 

        System.out.println("The predicted value of instance "+
                                Integer.toString(s1)+
                                ": "+prediction); 

        //Format the distribution
        String distribution="";
        for(int i=0; i <percentage.length; i=i+1)
        {
            if(i==value)
            {
                distribution=distribution+"*"+Double.toString(percentage[i])+",";
            }
            else
            {
                distribution=distribution+Double.toString(percentage[i])+",";
            }
        }
        distribution=distribution.substring(0, distribution.length()-1);

        System.out.println("Distribution:"+ distribution);
    }

}
```

The output from this is:

```
The predicted value of instance 0: no  
Distribution: *1, 0
```

Comment: Ooops I missed/misunderstood `distributionForInstance()`! Thank you for the complete answer, I'm sure other WEKA users in the future would appreciate it ^_^ You rock!

Comment: is it correct that if I have a binary outcome for a model, say "true" or "false", and this corresponds to an array with two elements, then the outcome variable's distribution are "true" is to array[0] and "false" is to array[1]?

Comment: I believe that is correct.  If you want to check the order the class values fall in that array check out the line included above "String prediction=originalTrain.classAttribute().value((int)value);".  Where value would be the index of the array.

Comment: Thank you, Mr. Walter. I really appreciate it!